# Emulating the GUI of an Android App in Docker

Tags: android, docker, android-studio

Im looking for methods to get an Android App running inside a Docker container which can access the GUI of the app.
The headless emulator then needs to be accessed from the outside.

For example, there is an App that has a button. When the App runs inside a container, there should be some functionality to click the button via outside functions (without changing the app).

I don't want to mimic API functionalities or distinct Code from the App. I want to try to access the GUI without knowing the code of the app. For this reason, I didn't find any tools or emulators that are able to do this.

Maybe you have ideas to solve this task.